# I need an easy example for `useEffect()` with clean up, on subscription

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React and I'm confused with this cleanup thing on `useEffect`. This example on [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1) isn't clear to me:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
      setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }

    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    return () => {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });
```

1. What does `ChatAPI` looks like? Is it an object, a component or something else?
2. Why are the `subscribeToFriendStatus` and `unsubscribeFromFriendStatus` can have `handleStatusChange` as the 2nd argument? Is `props.friend.id` being used as the argument for `handleStatusChange`? It's unclear to me.
3. Which part of the code makes it "subscription-type side effect"? I think it's because `handleStatusChange` being used as argument for the 2 `subscribe` functions but I'm not sure.

I have already understood the flow of useEffect in Mounting, Updating and Unmouting so you guys don't need to remind it for me.

Comment: It's just a pseudcode implementation; it means nothing. We're not meant to understand what ChatAPI does, just that it has the ability to register and unregister itself, which is exploited by `useEffect`.

Comment: Yeah I know that this is pseudocode, but it just doesnt make sense to me

Answer (score -1):

1. ChatAPI is an object from used chat API something like

   `let ChatAPI = new ChatAPIClient;`
2. I think it comes from DRY, so there is just one handler for it and  `subscribeToFriendStatus` can look like this

```
function subscribeToFriendStatus(id, handler){
    shouldSubscribe = true;
  handler(id, shouldSubscribe)
}
```

> Is props.friend.id being used as the argument for handleStatusChange?

It's possible

3. Whole useEffect hook is for side-effects. As I understand, Its main role is to change status as active and then run this subscription but I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: The answer to #3 is because the stuff happening inside `useEffect` depends on `props.friend.id`. When `props.friend.id` changes, the previous subscription needs to be unsubscribed and a new one needs to be created.

Comment: 2 isn’t because of dry. The point is to attach and detach the same exact handler function. Similar to adding and removing handlers for DOM events.

Comment: @Adam So the term "subscription" means "using parent's stuff like state, context, or ref" right? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @chaukhoa97 yes. That "stuff" that you're talking about is the basis for the dependencies array in React hooks like useMemo, useEffect, and useCallback. Anything that comes from the component tree that can change. For instance, `ChatAPI` lives outside the component tree, it won't change, and isn't a dependency.